# How Do I Play Forza Horizon 4?

Tags: forza-horizon-4

> ***Question:*** I am playing [Forza Horizon 4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forza_Horizon_4) developed by Play Ground Games on a [Microsoft Xbox One-X](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xbox_One#Xbox_One_X). I have passed the Demo Content and moved onto the Horizon Festival; where influence must be earned in order to move onto to the Autumn Stage. In the Horizon Festival I choose for my first car the Ford Focus RS. I then choose a "vanity plate" and some graphics for the vehicles. I also applied some "free tuning" to improve handling and performance. What do I do next ***in order*** to play in Horizon Festival racing events?

---

Compared to [this](https://youtu.be/UZt0-7QZ2s4?t=742) YouTube video I do not get placed into any racing events - instead I am shown a World map where I select a destination using cursor movements on the controller. I then press **A** to choose my route.  I begin driving and upon reaching my destination point I am told "You Have Arrived At Your Destination" - and nothing happens. What should I do next? Should I be pressing buttons and/or navigating menu options ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you approach an event, Press (x) when inside of its area to enter and begin setup/play the event.

Comment: So a natural follow up question is how do I "approach an event" . I do not recall seeing any such way to do so. I simply got into the Focus and starting driving.

Comment: You drive up to it. They will show up on your map and in your line of sight. Much like the video you posted.

Comment: that worked fine !